# Получить id комментария

Tags: php, html, mysql

Есть цикл for, который выводит все записи из базы данных. Как присвоить уникальный id, чтобы отправлять формы?

**Обновление**

```
do {?>
                    <div class="message" style="word-wrap:break-word;"><div id="text_message"><? echo $post[$i] ?>
<form action="add.php" method="POST" id="addlike">
                            <div id="like-dislike">
                                <input type="radio" id="like" value="<? echo $post[$i] ?>" name="rad" onclick="add_wall()"/>
                                    <label id="lab_tex" for="like"><span id="sp" ></span></label>
```

В массиве post хранятся комментарии.

Comment: @juniornew, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Что именно (и как) вы прикрутили? Вы бы хоть пример кода нам привели, чтобы ясно было, что вы делаете и что не получается.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$post[$i]['id']?>">
```

Comment: я сделал так:
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? $post['id']?>">
и в исходном коде все норм но когда нажимаю на лайк отправляет первое значение $post['id']

Comment: Можно полностью посмотреть код?

Comment: Проверти что у Вас в массиве, который выводите, с помощью print_r()

Comment: Возможно, Вам еще нужно увеличивать счетчик $i.
$i++;

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM $walls ORDER BY id DESC ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql)  or die(mysql_error());
    if ($result != 0){
      $r = '0';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
     $post[] = $row["text"];
     $times[] = $row['time'];